# SimpleXML Framework returns all nested elements

Tags: java, xml, nested, simple-framework

I have an xml document as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Calculations>
    <desc>Calculations Description</desc>
    <Calculation operator="ADD" valueA="1" valueB="2">
        <desc>First Description</desc>
        <owners>
        <owner id="1"><name>Alan</name></owner>
        <owner id="2"><name>Karen</name></owner>
        <owner id="3"><name>Isla</name></owner>
        <owner id="4"><name>Bethany</name></owner>
        </owners>
    </Calculation>
    <Calculation operator="SUBTRACT" valueA="3" valueB="1">
        <desc>Second Description</desc>
        <owners>
        <owner id="10"><name>Christopher</name></owner>
        <owner id="11"><name>David</name></owner>
        <owner id="12"><name>Matt</name></owner>
        <owner id="13"><name>Peter</name></owner>
        </owners>
        </Calculation>
    <Calculation operator="MULTIPLY" valueA="2" valueB="5">
        <desc>Third Description</desc>
        <owners>
        <owner id="10"><name>Christopher</name></owner>
            <owner id="11"><name>David</name></owner>
            <owner id="12"><name>Matt</name></owner>
            <owner id="13"><name>Peter</name></owner>
        </owners>
                </Calculation>
    <Calculation operator="DIVIDE" valueA="2" valueB="5">
        <desc>Fourth Description</desc>
        <owners>
        <owner id="10"><name>Christopher</name></owner>
            <owner id="11"><name>David</name></owner>
            <owner id="12"><name>Matt</name></owner>
            <owner id="13"><name>Peter</name></owner>
        </owners>
                </Calculation>
</Calculations>
```

I am attempting to deserialize it using the following java classes:

Calculations.java:

```
package Simple;

import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="Calculations")
public class Calculations {

    @Element(name="desc")
       private String text;

    @ElementList(inline=true)
       public static List<Calculation> calculations;


       public Calculations() {
          super();
       }  
       public List<Calculation> getCalculations() {
              return calculations;
           }
        public String getDescription() {
              return text;
           }

}
```

Calculation.java:

```
package Simple;

import java.util.List;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="Calculation")
public class Calculation {
    public Calculation() {
        super();
    }

    @Attribute(name="operator")
       private String operator;


    @ElementList
       public static List<Owner> owners;

    public String getOperator() {
          return operator;
       }

  public List<Owner> getOwners() {
          return owners;
       }

}
```

and owner.java:

```
package Simple;

import org.simpleframework.xml.Attribute;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name="Owner")
public class Owner {
    public Owner() {
        super();
    }

    @Attribute(name="id")
       private String id;

    @Element(name="name")
    private String name;

    public String getID() {
          return id;
       }

    public String getName() {
          return name;
       }
}
```

I have it running successfully (mostly) - for the moment it's just in a test project and I'm writing the details out to the console with a couple of for loops.

The trouble is that when I print it out, instead of each "Calculation" having 4 owners , what's being returned is that each calculation has 16 owners - all 16 owners are returned for each calculation, as shown from my console:

```
ADD
 - Alan
 - Karen
 - Isla
 - Bethany
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
SUBTRACT
 - Alan
 - Karen
 - Isla
 - Bethany
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
MULTIPLY
 - Alan
 - Karen
 - Isla
 - Bethany
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
DIVIDE
 - Alan
 - Karen
 - Isla
 - Bethany
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
 - Christopher
 - David
 - Matt
 - Peter
end
```

I've searched forums for hours and also been through the SimplXML tutorials and examples and I simply cannot find a clue as to why this is happening.

I assumed that when the "read" process iterated through that as it goes into each calculation, it would just pick the owners out of that iteration, but for some reason it's adding all of them to each calculation.

I'd appreciate any help you can give.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Must you use **static** List fields? Why not instance fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you not use **static** List fields, that instead you use **non-static** or instance List fields in your classes.

---

i.e., change this:

```
@ElementList
public static List<Owner> owners;
```

to this:

```
@ElementList
public List<Owner> owners; // not static
```

---

and the same for changing this:

```
@ElementList(inline=true)
public static List<Calculation> calculations;
```

to this:

```
@ElementList(inline=true)
public List<Calculation> calculations;
```

---

By being static, all instances of the class will share the same List, meaning all instances of Calculation will have the same list of Owners, and this may be a source of problems for you. Also you should strongly consider making the fields above private, and allowing access only through the getters and setters. Later you might want to only release a deep copy of the original List, and this can be accomplished only if you limit direct access to the fields.

Comment: That fixed the problem straight away, thank you, I'm really grateful.  Grateful too for the quick overview of the implications of both static and public/private.  They were set to private originally, I only set them to public just to see if it would make any difference to the problem I was having (and I just hadn't changed them back).  It will also prompt me to look further into the implications of 'static' which I've obviously misunderstood somewhere along the line.  Thanks again.